# How to validate (e.g. check if a list contains etc.) R6 objects in R?

Tags: r, validation, r6

How to validate if R6 objects i.e. if an R6 objects equals another R6 object.

Let's have an example class, and then create an object (as done here: https://r6.r-lib.org/articles/Introduction.html)

```
> Person <- R6Class("Person",
+                   public = list(
+                       name = NULL,
+                       hair = NULL,
+                       initialize = function(name = NA, hair = NA) {
+                           self$name <- name
+                           self$hair <- hair
+                           self$greet()
+                       },
+                       set_hair = function(val) {
+                           self$hair <- val
+                       },
+                       greet = function() {
+                           cat(paste0("Hello, my name is ", self$name, ".\n"))
+                       }
+                   )
+ )
> ann <- Person$new("Ann", "black")
Hello, my name is Ann.
```

However, when we try to validate our object against itself, it is not possible:

```
> ann == ann
Error in ann == ann : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Then we can create a list containing our objects, and check whether our object is on that list, but...

```
> listOfAnns <- list(ann, ann, ann, ann)
> ann %in% listOfAnns
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments
```

...it does not work.

So is there a way to do this type of validation in R?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `identical()`:

```r
ann <- Person$new("Ann", "black")
#> Hello, my name is Ann.

jo <- Person$new("jo", "blonde")
#> Hello, my name is jo.

identical(ann, ann)
#> [1] TRUE

identical(ann, jo)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Function "identical" seems to do the trick, doesn't it?

```
> identical(ann, ann)
[1] TRUE
> sum(unlist(lapply(seq_len(length(listOfAnns)), function(i) {identical(ann, listOfAnns[[i]])}))) > 0
[1] TRUE
```
Would someone confirm this? However, I do not get the logic of your identical.Person function. What is "public_fields" you are referring to?

Comment: Nevermind, that answer didn't make any sense. I changed it. I was not able to recreate the object that I used before, which had a `public_fields` entry with all fields as a list.